# icons don't displays in mozilla firefox

Tags: css, firefox

My CSS code:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.icon-star {
    content: url(../img/icons/star.png);
}
.icon-plus-sign-alt {
    content: url(../img/icons/icon-plus-sign-alt.png);
}
...
...
```

My HTML code:

```
<i class="icon-plus-sign-alt" title="INJURED" alt="INJURED"></i>
```

Why this icons don't displays in Firefox (v 27)? In Chrome, Opera and IE it's correct.

In Chrome:

[image]

In FF:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML. Plus a jsFiddle would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), the `content` property will generate content when it is used with **`before`** and **`after`**  **pseudo element**, not the HTML element itself. You need to change your code to

```
.icon-star:before {
  content: url(../img/icons/star.png);
}
.icon-plus-sign-alt:before {
  content: url(../img/icons/icon-plus-sign-alt.png);
}
```

This behavior is also defined in the [W3 standard](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content). I have no idea about why Chrome and Opera work with no pseudo element.